# Problema ao instalar OCI8 em uma vm do Vagrant

Tags: oracle, vagrant, php-7

Criei uma *VM* com o *Laravel Homestead* preciso instalar o *OCI8* nela:

Rodo o comando `sudo pecl install oci8` como informa [aqui](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/php_7_oci8_2_1)

*Porém recebo esse erro:*

> **ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/oci8/configure**
>   **--with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-oci8' failed**

Estou usando `PHP 7.1.0` não sei se tem alguma coisa a ver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente segui um tutorial (em inglês), vou passá-lo para a resposta e o linkarei ao final da resposta:

> Instalação do Oracle Instant Client

**1º passo:**

Faça o download do *[Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html)* e *SDK* do site da Oracle. Certifique-se de escolher a arquitetura correta para a instalação(32bit x86, 64bit x86_64). Você vai precisar fazer o upload dos arquivos para o seu servidor usando qualquer método que lhe convier.

**2º passo:**

Crie uma nova pasta para armazenar arquivos zip do *Oracle Instant Client* em seu servidor.

Executando o comando:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/oracle
```

**3º passo:**

Agora extraia os arquivos:

```
cd /opt/oracle

sudo unzip instantclient-basic-linux-12.1.0.2.0.zip

sudo unzip instantclient-sdk-linux-12.1.0.2.0.zip
```

**4º passo:**

Crie um link simbólico para os arquivos do *Instant Client*.

```
ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/libclntsh.so.12.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/libclntsh.so

ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/libocci.so.12.1 /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1/libocci.so
```

**5º passo:** (nessa etapa precisei alterar as permissões no `ld.so.conf.d` com `sudo chmod 777`)

Adicione a pasta ao ao `ldconfig`

```
echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient
```

**6º passo:**

Atualizar os vínculos de tempo de execução do vinculador dinâmico

```
sudo ldconfig
```

---

> Instalação do OCI8

**1º passo:** (não fiz essa etapa, usei o `php 7.1.1`)

Execute estes comandos para instalar o php-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev build-essential libaio1
```

**2º passo:**

Depois de instalado, precisamos obter o arquivo OCI8.

```
pecl install oci8-2.0.10
```

Quando o prompt perguntar onde está o *Instant Client* digite:

```
instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_1
```

**3º passo:**

Habilite a extensão do oci8 no

```
sudo echo "extension = oci8.so" >> /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

sudo echo "extension = oci8.so" >> /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

**4º passo:**

Reinicie o seu PHP e nginx/apache.

```
service php5-fpm restart

service nginx(ou apache) restart
```

Fonte: [syahzul](http://www.syahzul.com/2016/04/06/how-to-install-oci8-on-ubuntu-14-04-and-php-5-6/)